# Spring classpath resource overwritten

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a class which uses the following code:

```
@Value(value = "classpath:mail_template.html")
private Resource template;
```

According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access) tutorial this would allow me to get data from a file inside my jar file using `template.getInputStream()`. This worked correctly until another `mail_template.html` was added in another module.

My application has a `main_application` who's POM has the other modules as dependencies. The structure is as follows:

```
main_application
    |
    - modulue_1 (another module)
        |
        - src/main/java
        - src/main/resources
            |
            - mail_template.html
    - modulue_2 (my module)
        |
        - src/main/java
        - src/main/resources
            |
            - mail_template.html
```

So now my class uses module_1's `mail_template.html` instead of the one I have inside my module. As I understand this is the correct behavior since module_1 is loaded first and `@Value` gets injected with the first `mail_template.html` that it finds, but this would not be correct in my case since it overrides the  resource in module_2 (and subsequent modules as well) that has the same name in module_1.

Is it possible to specify to use the current class (or module) to find a resource in the `src/main/resources` directory in the `@Value` annotation? Or must I uniquely name every resource in every module to avoid this problem?

I have tried many different "classpath:" routes including:

```
@Value(value = "classpath:module_2/mail_template.html")
....
@Value(value = "classpath*:mail_template.html")
...
@Value(value = "classpath*:module_2/mail_template.html")
```

But all of these result in a `FileNotFoundException`.

### EDIT

Each module is composed as follows:

```
Maven POM Project
    Maven Java Application
        src/main/java
            base.package.with.module.name.as.suffix.package
        src/main/resources
            resource_files_if_needed
```

As stated, each module is declared as a dependency under the Maven Java Application `main_application` and each Maven Java Application uses a "base package" with the module's name as a suffix.

For example:

```
// main_application:
    package my.main.application
// module_1:
    package my.main.application.module1
// module_2:
    package my.main.application.module2
```

This is used so Spring can load the classes with `@Component` annotations using `<context:component-scan base-package="my.main.application" />` in the config file.

Comment: if you specify `classpath:<path>`, then wildcards won't work, and since there's a single classpath per classloader, you'd have to either define a classloader that only looked in your module, or you could change it to a value that would end up being referenced as a file instead, (use file://path/to/resource) you might be able to use relative paths to get you there

Comment: @Gus As I understand I can't use `file://path/to/resource` because the file is inside the JAR and it would give me the same FileNotFoundException.

Comment: First thing it finds on the classpath will be loaded. Everything else will be ignored. So you need uniquely named resources. The same applies to classes if they are in the same package with the same name you can override things. You could create your own `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` in your own code and create all sorts of issues with that... In the early Spring days we used t his mechanism to override certain Spring classes to add/extend functionality... (You didn't hear that from me ;) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum So basically what you are saying is that all the module's `src/main/resources` files are copied over to the classpath location regardless of whether they are in different locations/modules?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. They are in the jar, but as they are in the same location (the root). Only the first one loaded will actually be found. All jars are on the classpath but only one of the jars can contain a unique resource (and hence the first jar detected will be found). That is how classloaders and classloading works in Java.

Comment: @M.Deinum OK, having read your other comment I was wondering, is the loading determined by the order in which the dependencies are declared in the main POM file? Because my module's JAR is before the other module but the dependency of my module is declared last.

Comment: ok if your resources are only available via classpath, then they need to have unique paths.  I typically put the resources in a parallel path (if your classes are in org.jmhg92.module1, put the resources for it in org.jmhg92.module1 also)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one mail_template.html in the classpath. This is also true for classes with the same package and class name.

I would suggest to us a different directory name in the resource directory.

Comment: All of the modules use a base package (so spring is able to load the `@Component`s using this base) with a unique name, so there shouldn't be any problem with that. It's also not possible to change the directory since it is a Maven project and I have to keep the same structure throughout the application.

Comment: What do you mean by base package?

Comment: Please see my edits for more information about the base package

Comment: Those are different packages. If you have a class `foo.bar.MyClass` in module1 and `foo.bar.MyClass` in module 2 only the one from module 1 would be loaded.

Comment: That's exactly what i meant of the resources! Add module1 and module2 directories to src/main/resources

Comment: @M.Deinum This wouldn't be possible since I have say `foo.bar.MyClass` in module_1 and `foo.bar.baz.MyClass` in module_2

Comment: Hence they aren't the same. Only 1 resource with the unique name will be loaded. Your template has the same name and location in both jars and as such only the first will be loaded.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That would defeat the purpose since I have specific resources for each module, and `main_application/src/main/resources` has resources that only `main_application`

Comment: But it's the SAME that you are doing with the base packages! Either use it or you will still have the problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't know how it could be the same location. One is in `module_1/src/main/resources` and the other one is in `module_2/src/main/resources`

Comment: I storngly suggest a read on how maven packaging works. `src/main/resources` will be put in the root of the jar... i.e. no-package, default pacakge whatever you call it. The same applies to `src/main/java` everything that is in there, unless it is in a package, is in the root of the classppath. For both jars the template is in the root of the jar (I suggest you use unzip to unpack both jar files). Hence from a classpath perspective it is in the same. There is no src/main/resource or src/main/java those are just the root of the class (and maven uses it to store different types of sources).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have unzipped the JAR and all I see is that there is a `lib` folder where the modules (and other dependencies) are stored as a JAR file, and those JAR files have their respective `mail_template.html` at their root

Comment: I was referring to the 2 module jars. Spring Boot has a special jar which includes the dependencies in said `lib` dir. Those 2 modules have the same path for the `mail_template.html` (the name of the module isn't part of the unique path) and as such only 1 is seen.

Answer (score -1):

I beleive, it actually skips `classpath` in the `@Value` expression. I think the problem is `:` after `classpath`. The `:` in the `@Value` refers the separator character to separate property key and default value. 
For example, below code looks for key `project.123.gender` and if it is not available then returns `Male` as default.

`@Value("${project.123.gender:Male}")`

Could you try something like below? I have not tested it, but looks like that could be one possible issue. (note the extra `:` at start)

`@Value(value = ":classpath:mail_template.html")`

OR

`@Value(value = "${:classpath:mail_template.html"})`

Comment: The file isn't skipped since it loads another `mail_template.html` file, and according to the tutorial I linked under section "2.2. Using @Value" it shows that using `claspath:` is the correct way to refer to a resource using the annotation. Also, I tried using `:classpath:mail_template.html` and still had a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: The second option (`"${:classpath:mail_template.html}"`) just results in the same problem of using module_1's resource

Comment: No it doesn't skip `classpath:`. It will use a `ResourceEditor` to convert the `String` in the `@Value` annotation to a proper `Resource`. `classpath:` is used to denote a classpath based resource. (See the resource loading chapter of the spring reference guide). What you say is true when using value expressions i.e. t hings enclosed in  `${...}` inside the `@Value` annotation.